# I don't see why my code isn't taking the value of the input box and making a new object

Tags: javascript, object

The code for this is at

This is the Javascript :

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

    function Person(fullname, job, country, city) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.job = job;
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
    }

    var fullname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var job = document.getElementById("job").value;
    var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;

    var me = new Person(fullname, job, country, city);

    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = me.fullname + ". Congratulations an object has been made with your information stored in it, the following information is what you have given us. Your job is a " + me.job + "You live in" + me.city + "," + me.country + ".";
};
```

Comment: Do you really have elements with ids "submit" and "p" in the document? Does your JavaScript code run after they've been added to the DOM?

Comment: Which input box value isn't getting into the object? None of them? Also, as Pointy has asked, do you have an element with the id attribute of "p" or are you trying to get a <p> element?

Comment: You should put the constructor function outside of your event handler.

Comment: Please view the console and see the errors it displays.

Comment: Why are you creating a new object and filling it with the values, when you could use the values themselves directly in the string your are constructing?

Comment: Comment deleted. Post the HTML if you still need an answer.

Comment: <html>
    <body>
        <div>
  
    <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder ="Full Name" name="fullname">
    <input type="text" id="job" placeholder ="Job" name="job">
    <input type="text" id="country" placeholder ="Country" name="country">
    <input type="text" id="city" placeholder ="City" name="city">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            
            <p id="p1"></p>
</div>
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There's no id on the submit button use `document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]')`; instead.
- The id for that `<p>` is `p1`

  ```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>

      <div>

          <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder ="Full Name" name="fullname">
          <input type="text" id="job" placeholder ="Job" name="job">
          <input type="text" id="country" placeholder ="Country" name="country">
          <input type="text" id="city" placeholder ="City" name="city">

          <input type="submit" value="Submit">

          <p id="p1"></p>
      </div>
      <script>
    document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').onclick = function() {

      function Person(fullname, job, country, city) {
          this.fullname = fullname;
          this.job = job;
          this.country = country;
          this.city = city;
      }

      var fullname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var job = document.getElementById("job").value;
      var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
      var city = document.getElementById("city").value;

      var me = new Person(fullname, job, country, city);

      document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = me.fullname + ". Congratulations an object has been made with your information stored in it, the following information is what you have given us. Your job is a " + me.job + "You live in" + me.city + "," + me.country + ".";
  };
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>

        <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder ="Full Name" name="fullname">
        <input type="text" id="job" placeholder ="Job" name="job">
        <input type="text" id="country" placeholder ="Country" name="country">
        <input type="text" id="city" placeholder ="City" name="city">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        <p id="p1"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: **first** this is an edit not an answer, so please [*update*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35421481/edit) your question and include this code. **second** here you have `id="p1"`, and in the javascript you have `document.getElementById("p")` .. **`p`** instead of **`p1`** ??